# OpportunityLineItem:- Field Integrity Error

Tags: apex, trigger, error, opportunity-lineitem, pricebookentry

I am trying to automate the following functionality: When an opportunity stage becomes '`Pending Payment`', insert 2 '`OpportunityLineItems`' using 2 predefined Products.

This is my current code. I am calling the class on an after update event on the `Opportunity` Sobject:

```
public void addProductWhenStageIsPendingPayment() {

        Set<id> ids = new Set<Id>();
        for(Opportunity o : newOpportunities.values()){
            if(o.stagename=='Pending Payment')
                ids.add(o.id);
        }


        List<Opportunity> opps = [Select id, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c,CurrencyIsoCode,PriceBook2id from Opportunity where id in: ids];// and  Start_Date__c!=null and  End_Date__c!=null];

        List<Product2> products = [Select id,name, CurrencyIsoCode from Product2];
        Id product1Id=NULL;
        id product2id=NULL;

        list<PriceBookEntry> priceBookList = [SELECT Id, Product2Id, Product2.Id, Product2.Name FROM PriceBookEntry 
                                             WHERE  PriceBook2.isStandard=true ];
        Id priceBook1Id=NULL;
        id priceBook2id=NULL;

        List<OpportunityLineItem> oppsline = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

        for(Opportunity op : opps)  
        {
            // get the product ids
             for(Product2 p : products)
            {
                if(p.name=='Name A' & p.CurrencyIsoCode==op.CurrencyIsoCode)
                product1Id=p.id;
                if(p.name=='Name B' &   p.CurrencyIsoCode==op.CurrencyIsoCode)
                product2Id=p.id;
             }

            // get the price book ids
            for(PriceBookEntry pbe : priceBookList)
            {
                if(pbe.Product2Id== product1Id)
                    priceBook1id = pbe.id;
                if(pbe.Product2Id == product2Id)
                    priceBook2id = pbe.id;
            }



            Date startDate = op.Start_Date__c;
            Date endDate = op.End_Date__c;
            Integer monthDiff = startDate.monthsBetween(endDate);
            monthDiff++;

            for(integer i=0; i<monthDiff ; i++)
            {
                OpportunityLineItem oli1 = new OpportunityLineItem( PricebookEntryId=  priceBook1Id  , Opportunityid=op.id,UnitPrice=1000,Quantity=22,ServiceDate=endDate,  Description='Name A',Estimate_Actual__c='Estimated');
                OpportunityLineItem oli2 = new OpportunityLineItem( PricebookEntryId=  priceBook2Id , Opportunityid=op.id,UnitPrice=250,Quantity=22,ServiceDate=endDate,    Description='Name B',Estimate_Actual__c='Estimated');
                oppsline.add(oli1);
                oppsline.add(oli2);
            }

        }

        insert oppsline;

    }
```

This is the current error I am getting:

> Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Apex trigger MasterOpportunityTrigger caused an unexpected
>   exception, contact your administrator: MasterOpportunityTrigger:
>   execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert
>   failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: PricebookEntryId
>   (pricebook entry is in a different pricebook than the one assigned to
>   the opportunity): [PricebookEntryId]:
>   Class.ClassOpportunityHandler.addProductWhenStageIsPendingPayment:
>   line 81, column 1

Comment: does the opportunity have the same standard pricebook as the pricebookentry?

Comment: This is obviously a method that's part of a larger class. What are you passing to the class? If this trigger is firing on Opportunity, are you passing trigger.new to your class? There really should be no reason to have to query Opportunity to obtain the values you're returning. You should already have that info. If calling the method directly, why don't we see how you're passing it in?

Comment: So the presented method is inside  a helper class for the Trigger on the Opportunity Object. Inside the constructor of the helper class I am only passing the Trigger.new and Trigger.old values which are refferenced in the newOpportunity.values()